# Give a individual name for files while multiupload/multistorage

Tags: javascript, express, node.js-fs

I have to upload multiple-files (already done), but each of them have to have a specific name (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc). I've tried something like this, but the problem is that I can't change the file name, the files keep their original names

```
app.post('/upload', uploadMiddleware, (req, res) => {      
  const files = req.files;
  
  files.forEach((file) => {
    const filePath = `uploads/${file.filename}`;
    
    fs.rename(file.path, filePath, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error appropriately and send an error response
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to store the file' });
      }
    });
  })
  
  res.redirect('/gameCustom')

});
```

Comment: What is the content of `err` on the callback ? That should give you a hint of why it's failing